# Jumping a sprite while moving in a Bezier action

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a game and I need the sprite to jump (move up and down basically) while its moving on a bezier path so it only moves vertically while it follows the path. If I do thids while it's moving along the bezier path:

```
[mySprite runAction:[CCJumpBy actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(0,0) height:10 jumps:1]];
```

It jumps vertically but instantly it return to the position on the path. What I want is to jump relative to the path.

Anyone knows something about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) update:(ccTime) t
{
    // parabolic jump (since v0.8.2)
    ccTime frac = fmodf( t * jumps_, 1.0f );
    ccTime y = height_ * 4 * frac * (1 - frac);
    y += delta_.y * t;
    ccTime x = delta_.x * t;
    [target_ setPosition: ccp( ((CCNode*)target_).position.x + x, ((CCNode*)target_).position.y + y )];
}
```

Comment: Could you Explan Clearly. what is "delta_.x", "jumps_" and "delta_.y"?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I could imagine doing that is

- put mySprite on the blank layer
- do regular up and down action for mySprite item.
- when you need, run action to the blank layer to Jump.

This would mix two different Action.